# T4 Toolbox problems

Tags: c#, t4, t4-toolbox

I downloaded and installed the latest  version of the [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30030) for VIsual Studio 2010, in an attempt to create LINQ business objects, but I'm having some troubles with it. First, I was getting errors saying it couldn't find T4Toolbox.tt and T4Toolbox\LinqtoSql.tt in my project directory, but that's not where they are installed. Am I to provide the absolute path to them in my template?

In trying to get this to work, I removed the files I added via the instructions, and added them again. This time the error changed to "File doesn't exist: "\XML\SCHEMAS\DBMLSCHEMA.XSD". I have populated the dbml file using the server explorer.

Both errors reference the same file, the "ServerBiz.tt" file that I created from a Linq to SQL Model template in the Code Generation section in Visual Studio. They've also both generated the warning "The C# 2.0 and C# 3.5 compilers are no longer supported. Templates will always be compiled with the version 4 compiler instead of 'v3.5' as specified.", though switching the language attribute in the .tt file to "C#" cleared that up (and has had no effect on the errors I'm receiving). I've also got no color highlighting in the editor, though something tells me I just need to install a tool or something to get that to work. But I thought I'd mention these things in case they were relevant.

Update:
I was mistaken, the search did find T4Toolbox.tt in C:\Program Files\T4 Toolbox. I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: If you have not resolved this issue, you may want to post it at http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/thread/list.aspx.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this and the issue was fixed in the latest version. See my post [here](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=78006) for details.